# Squash dataframe by a certain column to rows that contains first and last timestamps and mean of values

Tags: python, pandas

I have marked groups of data ordered by timestamps and I want to reduce it to the start timestamp and last timestamp and get the average of the values corresponding to that mark in that group. Example starting dataframe:

```
          timestamp          value      mark
1   2016-11-07 11:00:00       0.781726     1  
2   2016-11-07 11:03:00       0.812757     2  
3   2016-11-07 11:05:00       0.845348     2  
4   2016-11-07 11:07:00       0.817394     2  
5   2016-11-07 11:11:00       0.760787     1  
6   2016-11-07 11:13:00       0.807892     1 
7   2016-11-07 11:15:00       0.812965     1  
8   2016-11-07 11:18:00       0.822001     1
```

What I want to achieve:

```
        start_timestamp         end_timestamp  (mean_)value  mark  
1   2016-11-07 11:00:00   2016-11-07 11:00:00     0.781726      1
2   2016-11-07 11:03:00   2016-11-07 11:07:00     0.825166      2
3   2016-11-07 11:11:00   2016-11-07 11:18:00     0.800911      1
```

Any idea of the best way to do this? Should I first mark each batch with a unique mark?

Comment: Indeed, make the mark unique, do a `groupby`, take the first and last item within that group for start/end_timestamp, and do an average on the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by `Series` of unique `groups` from duplicated column `mark` and then [`aggregate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html) [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html), [`last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) and [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html):

```
print ((df.mark != df.mark.shift()).cumsum())
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    2
5    3
6    3
7    3
8    3
Name: mark, dtype: int32

df1 = df.groupby((df.mark != df.mark.shift()).cumsum()) \
         .agg({'timestamp': ['first','last'], 'value':'mean', 'mark': 'first'})

#reset MultiIndex in columns
df1.columns = ['_'.join(col) for col in df1.columns]
#if necessary rename columns
df1 = df1.rename(columns=({'timestamp_first':'start_timestamp', 
                           'timestamp_last':'end_timestamp',
                           'mark_first':'mark','value_mean':'(mean_)value'})) \
          .rename_axis(None)

print (df1)         
      start_timestamp       end_timestamp  mark  (mean_)value
1 2016-11-07 11:00:00 2016-11-07 11:00:00     1      0.781726
2 2016-11-07 11:03:00 2016-11-07 11:07:00     2      0.825166
3 2016-11-07 11:11:00 2016-11-07 11:18:00     1      0.800911
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually have more columns on the left. How where would I put them so I don't lose that info? In the agg or the group by? Or should I first group by them before this operation.

Comment: If there are another columns, there has to be aggregate too. Add another values to `agg` `dict` like `.agg({'timestamp': ['first','last'], 'value':'mean', 'mark': 'first', 'col1': 'first', 'col2': 'mean', 'col3': 'cum'})`